# Center align caption on margin

Tags: floats, captions, margins, koma-script

I am trying to align figure caption on the outer margin with koma-script, but no matter what I tried the option `centeredbeside` does not work.

```
\documentclass[captions=centeredbeside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{figure1}
\begin{captionbeside}{Caption beside figure.}[o][0.3\textwidth]
\end{captionbeside}
\label{fig:death-miser}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Besides, captions always appear on the right margin (not on the outer margin).

I have also tried:

```
\usepackage[outercaption,wide]{sidecap}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{c}
```

It works better, but the caption is still on the right margin, even if the page is even. I tried using `mparhack` to fix this but it did not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two points that have to be done differently.

1. The `\centering` command can be dropped.
2. The figure itself has to go into the `captionbeside` environment.

With a bit more text to show the final alignment this then looks like the following.

```
\documentclass[
  captions=centeredbeside
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % to be deleted in actual document

\begin{document}
  \blindtext  % to be deleted in actual document

  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{captionbeside}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}[o][0.75\textwidth]
      \includegraphics{figure1}
    \end{captionbeside}
    \label{fig:death-miser}
  \end{figure}

  \blindtext  % to be deleted in actual document
\end{document}
```

For the correct outer alignment of all captions you will probably need more than one compiler run as mentioned in the »[KOMA-Script](http://texdoc.net/pkg/koma-script)« user guide.

---

[image]

---

**Update**

As suggested in the comment the »[floatrow](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow)« package does the job quite well. Note the starred `figure*` environment.

```
\documentclass[
  captions=centeredbeside
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[widefigure]{
  facing=yes,
  margins=hangoutside,
  capposition=beside,
  capbesideposition={center,outside},
  floatwidth=\textwidth
}

\usepackage{blindtext}  % to be deleted in actual document

\setcapindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
  \blindtext  % to be deleted in actual document

  \begin{figure*}[!ht]
    \includegraphics{figure1}
    \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}\label{fig:dummy-1}
  \end{figure*}

  \blindtext  % to be deleted in actual document

  \clearpage
  \blindtext  % to be deleted in actual document

  \begin{figure*}[!ht]
    \includegraphics{figure1}
    \caption{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}\label{fig:dummy-2}
  \end{figure*}

  \blindtext  % to be deleted in actual document
\end{document}
```

For details I suggest to take look at the package manual.

---

[image][image]

Comment: It works fine, but I still cannot move the caption to the margin (like a marginpar).

Comment: For captions in the margins you should take a look at the »[floatrow](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow)« package. But this would make the other mechanism obsolete.

Comment: I think for margin captions it is much easier to just use `marginpar` and `captiononf` than `floatrow`-- otherwise, your answer works perfectly for captions inside the text block.

Comment: @Joseph: Oh, I wouldn't say so. See the update.